# mysql xml export from table - return an error

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm executing the below query

> mysql --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM testdb.nodes1' > file.xml

.

but it return always same error as mentioned below.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysql  --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM testdb.nodes1' >
>   file.xml' at line 1

kindly answer me..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you run this query in mysql console or in mysql-workbench. This is wrong way.

This query is for run in command line: bash or similar in Linux and cmd in Windows.